# Specular intensity not imported from Blender into Unity

Tags: unity, blender, specular

For my current project I'm using diffuse materials for my models in Blender but I do not want any Specular Intensity so I've set that to 0. Yet in Unity there is still a specular highlight and the material has a Smoothness of 0.5. Does Unity actually read Specular Intensity or am I missing some crucial detail?

I haven't been able to find any details on what the .blend-import actually reads and I can see a setting called Glossiness in the .mat-files created by Unity is set to 0.5.